# How to freez first row of a gridview in asp.net having both(horizontal and vertical) scrollbar

Tags: c#, css, asp.net

How to freez first row of a gridview in asp.net having both(horizontal and vertical) scrollbar in asp.net c#.

Comment: Try this http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/42322/How-to-Freeze-GridView-Header-While-Scrolling

Comment: its not working....

<style>
        .HeaderFreez
        {
            position:relative ;
            top:expression(this.offsetParent.scrollTop);
            z-index: 10;
        }
    </style>

<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server">
                <HeaderStyle CssClass="HeaderFreez" />
            </asp:GridView>

after running the code its show Invalid property value
for 

top: expression(this.offsetParent.scrollTop);